# Creating WebServer with 5000 port with AT command(ESP-01f)

Tags: esp8266, pins, web-server

I'm setting webserver with toggle led. I want to create global webserver. I`m mean hat use server with global ip. For it I must use port too. global ip/local ip:port.
I want to create on 5000 port. I'm used for ESP-01f and connect it arduino. Communicating by SoftwareSerial. I used AT+CIPSTA for static ip. When I used AT+CIPSERVER=1,5000 it worked. But when I connect to it, it works, but in second connection it doesn't want to connect itor when I use digitalWrite it doesn't connect to this server. How can I solute this problem?

code:

```cpp
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>



SoftwareSerial softSerial(10, 11);
String ssid = "ssid";
String ip = "staticip";
String gateway="gateway";
String sub="submask;
String password = "password";
String _response = "";
#define DEBUG true
void setup()
{

  Serial.begin(115200);

pinMode(2,OUTPUT);

  softSerial.begin(115200);
  connectWifi();
}

void connectWifi() {

  do {

    sendData("AT+RESTORE\r\n", 5000, DEBUG);
  } while (softSerial.find("OK"));
  do {

    sendData("AT\r\n", 2000, DEBUG);
  } while (softSerial.find("OK"));
  do {

    sendData("AT+CWMODE=1\r\n", 1000, DEBUG);
  } while (softSerial.find("OK"));
  do {

    sendData("AT+CWJAP=\"" + ssid + "\",\"" + password + "\"\r\n", 5000, DEBUG);
  } while (softSerial.find("OK"));
   do {

    sendData("AT+CIPSTA=\"" + ip + "\",\"" + gateway +"\",\"" + sub + "\"\r\n", 2000, DEBUG);
  } while (softSerial.find("OK"));
  do {

    sendData("AT+CIFSR\r\n", 1000, DEBUG);
  } while (softSerial.find("OK"));
  do {

    sendData("AT+CIPMUX=1\r\n", 1000, DEBUG);
  } while (softSerial.find("OK"));
  do {

    sendData("AT+CIPSERVER=1,5000\r\n", 1000, DEBUG);
  } while (softSerial.find("OK"));





}

String sendData(String command, const int timeout, boolean debug)
{


  String response = "";

  softSerial.print(command);        long int time = millis();
  while ((time + timeout) > millis())
  {
    while (softSerial.available())
    {

      char c = softSerial.read();
      response += c;
    }
  }

  if (debug)
  {
    Serial.print(response);
  }

  return response;
}

void loop()
{

if(softSerial.available()){
  if(softSerial.find("+IPD,"){
   int connectionId = softSerial.read()-48;
softSerial.find("pin/");
int pin = softSerial.read()-48;

String htmlCode = "<label>"+String(pin)+"</label>";
digitalWrite(pin,HIGH);
sendData("AT+CIPSEND="+String(connectionId)+","+htmlCode.length()+"\r\n",1000,DEBUG);
sendData(htmlCode+"\r\n",1000,DEBUG);


sendData("AT+CIPCLOSE="+String(connectionId),3000,DEBUG);



  }
}
}
```

Comment: don't use restore. it clears the settings part of the flash. you wear out the flash. use AT+RST. set AT+CWAUTOCONN=0 if you don't want the esp8266 to start the connection on startup or use _CUR commands to not save the connection to flash

Comment: you should read all the request bytes. what is on pin 2?

Comment: On pin 2 led...

Comment: How can I read all request bytes

Comment: And sometimes it write -49. WHY.

Comment: use the WiFiEsp library

Comment: `read()` returns -1 if no data are available. you subtract -48

Comment: Juraj WIFIEsp Library. How can I use it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97252/discussion-between-thegamercoder-and-juraj).